# How to programatically change Windows 10 accent color?

Tags: windows, registry

I want to make a script to change my accent color to a random color every day, using a command line or whatever I can find.

I found that I can change the "AccentColorMenu" in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent` in the registry to immediately change the color of window title bars and borders (and thus use reg.exe on command line). But changing "StartColorMenu" does nothing.

And preferrably I would like to change the color the same way control panel does it so the same color conversions are done for start menu etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this program](https://rammichael.com/getting-brighter-colors-in-windows-10) that can be used on the command line to do exactly what I want (in WSL because getting a random color was a lot easier):

```
'Windows 10 color control.exe' -accent_color $(openssl rand -hex 3)
```

While program is a few years out of date and some of its functionality doesn't seem to work anymore (Accent color always overrides DWM color and disabling new auto-color accent algorithm doesn't seem to do anything), it works perfectly to just set the system accent color just like if you were to set it in Settings.